# Ionic reset panning value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, panning

I want to reset my panning value. Basicly what i want todo is when the value hits -130 it should put the panning value to 0 again.

My code:

```
swipeEvent($e) {
  if ($e.deltaX <= -130) {
      document.getElementById("button").click();
      console.log('swiped left')
      };
  if ($e.deltaX < -131) { $e.deltaX == 0 }
}
```

I tried it with this code already:

```
if ($e.deltaX < -131) { $e.deltaX = 0 }
```

sadly this didn't worked.

Could someone help me please ? Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it!

I just had to change the HTML from this:

```
<div class="cards" (pan)='swipeEvent($event)'>
```

to this:

```
<div class="cards" (swipe)='swipeEvent($event)'>
```

TS:

```
swipeEvent($e) {
  if ($e.deltaX <= -130) {
      document.getElementById("button").click();
      console.log('swiped left')
      };
}
```

Hope this helps someone in the future!